# Schengen Visa photo printing error

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, schengen, long-stay-visas

My wife received her Schengen visa for Iceland today. Her face is clearly visible but there is a portion of her shoulder that wasn't printed. We have also reached out to the embassy just now, I thought I would ask the experts here as well.

I have 2 questions:

1. How common is a photograph printing error?
2. Would this would cause any problems during boarding and immigration?

[image]

Comment: As you see from the photo, the top part of the background is removed. Sometimes it may happen that part of dress is interpreted as background (and quality check failed). But as hint: next time try to dress with a dark and uniform colour (and a good uniform light background).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi That makes sense, thanks for the analysis. Do you think this could be a problem during boarding or immigration?

Comment: No, I do not think it is a problem. Nothing important there, and you see that the background is "official"

Comment: That is relieving to hear. Just to be super safe, is there any mechanism in place to request the embassy for a supporting document where they explain this situation and confirm that the visa is valid?

Comment: I would guess if it was to cause issues, that would have been when your visa was being processed.